# How can I retrieve all shards in my application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently learning to work with shards to develop a Saas application, and I might need to list the possible shards to superadmins or for rake tasks, here is my setup:

```ruby
# config/database.yml

development:
  example_one:
    <<: *default
    database: db/example_one.sqlite3
  example_two:
    <<: *default
    database: db/example_two.sqlite3
  example_three:
    <<: *default
    database: db/example_three.sqlite3
```

```ruby
# app/models/application_record.rb

class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class

  connects_to shards: {
    example_one: { writing: :example_one, reading: :example_one },
    example_two: { writing: :example_two, reading: :example_two },
    example_three: { writing: :example_three, reading: :example_three }
  }
end
```

I know that during a shard transaction I can return the current shard with this method

```ruby
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(shard: :example_three) do
   ActiveRecord::Base.current_shard
end

# :example_three
```

---

Is there a way/method to list all shards like this?

```ruby
[:example_one, :example_two, :example_three]
```

or the way the application record is receiving it without creating a constant just for this

```ruby
{
  example_one: { writing: :example_one, reading: :example_one },
  example_two: { writing: :example_two, reading: :example_two },
  example_three: { writing: :example_three, reading: :example_three }
}
```

I might use this for migrating specific migrations to a specific shard only (like a database for configurations only), if there is a better way of doing it, I am open to suggestions as well (but I would still like to know if it is possible to list them)

Comment: It seems like you might be able to get there as follows: `ActiveRecord::Base.connection_handler.connection_pool_list(:all)` This will return any Array of all the [`ConnectionPool`s](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb#L102). From here you can access the role/shard/db_config etc. for each connection

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

app/models/application_record.rb

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  primary_abstract_class

  SHARDS = {
    example_one: { writing: :example_one, reading: :example_one },
    example_two: { writing: :example_two, reading: :example_two },
    example_three: { writing: :example_three, reading: :example_three }
  }

  connects_to shards: SHARDS
end
```

config/initializers/shards.rb

```
SHARDS = ApplicationRecord::SHARDS
```

To use it:

```
SHARDS.each do |shard, _|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(shard: shard) do
    # do something
  end
end
```